# C# IsBetween String Logic

Tags: c#-4.0

Looking for either a solution, some ideas or being point in the right direction on how to resolve a problem.

Basically, I have to figure out if a string value is in between a Low and High string value.  However, the values are in a format which String.Compare will not work.  But, a human can easily figure out.

For example, one of my ranges is Low: A7, High A12.  A8 fits in between those values but String.Compare says it does not. A13 would not fit between the values.

Other examples of Low and High values are:

**Low Value - High Value**

1A1 - 1A12

25W00 - 25W050

42W1 - 42W296

W232N0002 - W232N000598

In the above examples 1A2 would fit between the Low High Value of 1A1 and 1A12, but 1A100 would not.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I know this had to have been encountered before.

Comment: Will the strings be in known formats? Because it seems to me that the only way to solve this is to break the string up into sections and compare section by section. You will probably need to come up with a set of rules to handle special cases - like if the first string is 42W1 and the second string is 44W3, and the string you are checking against the range is 43W4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could use some optimization, but it's a proof of concept.
Just convert the letters to numerical values and compare the results:

```
private bool ValueIsBetween(string value, string lowValue, string highValue)
{
    long low = long.Parse(ConvertToNumber(lowValue));
    long high = long.Parse(ConvertToNumber(highValue));
    long val = long.Parse(ConvertToNumber(value));
    return val > low && val < high;
}

private string ConvertToNumber(string value)
{
    value = value.ToUpper();
    value = value.Replace("A", "0");
    value = value.Replace("B", "1");
    value = value.Replace("C", "2");
    value = value.Replace("D", "3");
    value = value.Replace("E", "4");
    value = value.Replace("F", "5");
    value = value.Replace("G", "6");
    value = value.Replace("H", "7");
    value = value.Replace("I", "8");
    value = value.Replace("J", "9");
    value = value.Replace("K", "10");
    value = value.Replace("L", "11");
    value = value.Replace("M", "12");
    value = value.Replace("N", "13");
    value = value.Replace("O", "14");
    value = value.Replace("P", "15");
    value = value.Replace("Q", "16");
    value = value.Replace("R", "17");
    value = value.Replace("S", "18");
    value = value.Replace("T", "19");
    value = value.Replace("U", "20");
    value = value.Replace("V", "21");
    value = value.Replace("W", "22");
    value = value.Replace("X", "23");
    value = value.Replace("Y", "24");
    value = value.Replace("Z", "25");

    return value;
}
```

---

**Results:**

```
ValueIsBetween("1A2", "1A1", "1A12");
```

true

```
ValueIsBetween("1A100", "1A1", "1A12");
```

false

```
ValueIsBetween("43W4", "42W1", "44W3");
```

true

**Edit:**
Try this improved algorithm instead:

```
private bool ValueIsBetween(string value, string lowValue, string highValue)
{
    return !ValueIsLessThan(value, lowValue) && ValueIsLessThan(value, highValue);
}

private bool ValueIsLessThan(string value, string compareTo)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+");
    var matchesB = Regex.Matches(compareTo, "[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+");

    var count = matches.Count < matchesB.Count ? matches.Count : matchesB.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        long val;
        long val2;
        if (long.TryParse(matches[i].Value, out val))
        {
            if (long.TryParse(matchesB[i].Value, out val2))
            {
                if (val > val2) return false;
                if (val < val2) return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (matches[i].Value.CompareTo(matchesB[i].Value) > 0 ) return false;
            if (matches[i].Value.CompareTo(matchesB[i].Value) < 0 ) return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

**Results:**

```
ValueIsBetween("B431Z543", "A0", "Z9");
```

true

```
ValueIsBetween("4B31Z543", "A0", "Z9");
```

false

```
ValueIsBetween("1A2", "1A1", "1A12");
```

true

```
ValueIsBetween("1A100", "1A1", "1A12");
```

false

```
ValueIsBetween("43W4", "42W1", "44W3");
```

true

```
ValueIsBetween("W5", "CC4", "CC6");
```

false

```
ValueIsBetween("W8B4", "W5C3", "W7C3");
```

false

```
ValueIsBetween("W5C4", "W5C3", "C7W3");
```

false

Comment: Take care regarding false positives. I haven't tried it, but would expect `ValueIsBetween("W5", "CC4", "CC6")` to come back true when it should be false.

Comment: Matthew brings up a good point, you may need to change the approach if you start getting false positives.

Comment: See my latest edit, that handled every case mentioned and everything I could think of...

Answer (score 0):

Build a class, probably abstract, with sub classes for each pattern.

The pattern for "25W00" could be `^(?<LEFTTHING>.{2})(?<MIDDLETHING>.{1})(?<RIGHTTHING>.{2})$`

In your class, capture each Regex group as a string or numeric as appropriate.

I suppose you could come up with some conventions so you might even be able to have a single Type - and pass in that pattern to the constructor.

You may even have some kind of really smart class where you pass in two strings and a common pattern. This super class builds appropriate "comparable" classes (as per above) and returns a boolean result of the comparison. Your client code would be very clean in this case.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the non-numeric parts are fixed (i.e. you aren't searching for *1B1* being between *1A1* and *1C1*), you could use a regex to expand the numerical values to a certain fixed width, so you could then compare the strings.

For example, using

```
static Regex digits = new Regex(@"\d+");

static string ExpandDigits(string s)
{
    return digits.Replace(s, m => string.Format("{0:D10}", int.Parse(m.ToString())));
}
```

then calling `ExpandDigits("W232N0002")` yields `W0000000232N0000000002`.

You could have a comparison method like this:

```
static bool IsInRange(string lower, string upper, string test)
{
    test = ExpandDigits(test);
    lower = ExpandDigits(lower);

    if (lower.CompareTo(test) <= 0)
    {
        upper = ExpandDigits(upper);
        if (test.CompareTo(upper) <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I appreciate it.